# VR Headset Simulator

Tags: arcore, virtual-reality, hololens, oculus, htc-vive

Is it possible to code a program for HoloLens or Ocullus Rift or HTC Vice with AR Core? 
And is there a simulator for a VR headset like HoloLens or Ocullus Rift or HTC Vice to experiment the code with if you don't have a VR Headset?

Answer (score 2):

There's a HoloLens emulator available here that generally works similar to the device.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-the-hololens-emulator

Be aware that it does not emulate the ARM or 32-bit x86 chips actually on the devices so it may run things the actual devices will not.

There's also a WMR simulator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-the-windows-mixed-reality-simulator

This allows you to run SteamVR apps or WMR UWP apps as though you have a WMR headset.

It allows you to see a camera which you can move with your mouse and two virtual motion controllers which you can also move around and interact with.

You'll need this plugin for SteamVR: https://store.steampowered.com/app/719950/Windows_Mixed_Reality_for_SteamVR/

Answer (score 0):

There is a WebXR Emulator chrome extension available for testing XR applications without a hardware VR headset: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webxr-api-emulator/mjddjgeghkdijejnciaefnkjmkafnnje?hl=en